# How can registerJs work with beforaction() in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i created module .then in side module before action i am calling registerJs but is not working.

```
public function beforeAction($action){
    $js=Yii::getAlias('@webroot/assets_app/js/login.js');
    $this->getView()->registerJs($js, \yii\base\View::POS_END); 
 }
```

its showing Undefined class constant 'POS_END'

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `web` namespace

```
\yii\web\View::POS_END
```

*EDIT*

Just noticed, If you want to register a js file you need to use [registerJsFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail). The default position for that is `POS_END`

So all you need is,

```
public function beforeAction($action){
    $js = Yii::getAlias('@webroot/assets_app/js/login.js');
    $this->getView()->registerJsFile($js); 
}
```

Comment: so what is \yii\web\View::POS_END ?